# about other person's python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question.
I'm noob of Python and I received python code from person who have master's degree. The professor said it works. But the code isn't working and I noticed that it has codes like

```
print 'SoC effect elimination !! '
```

I only know that print in python should be

```
print('Soc effect elimination!!')
```

It needs to have brackets. So I want to know is there any program, other method or other environment(I'm using anaconda and pycharm community edition) I can use to have the code work. Thank you.

Comment: The first method works in Python 2 only.  The second method works in either Python 2 or Python 3.

Comment: print without parentheses is in indication that the code was probably written for Python 2. So, you will probably have to work at porting this code to work on Python 3.

Comment: Your professor is right. You need Python 2 to run it.

Comment: thx a lot. I'm going to download anaconda for python 2

Answer (score 1):

In python 2 `print` was a statement and it is used like this:

```
print 'foo bar'
```

However, in python 3 it was changed to be a function:

```
print('foo bar')
```

So you need to use the code in python 2, or add parentheses to each print in the code

Comment: Adding a parentheses to each print statement is not how upgrade from python 2 to python 3.  And "you should use Python 2" is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Alexander why? The question is how to get the code to work, and this is a short answer but provides at least one valid solution (use Python 2), and possibly another (add parentheses - which will work if there aren't other Python 2-specific quirks in the code).

Comment: @perigon because python 3 is quite different from python 2, not only just parentheses. This is definitely not a good answer at all... Not to mention SyntaxError is the first thing Python throws in your face in situation like this. Not getting more information before answering is just irresponsible in my opinion.

Comment: How is "Use Python 2 to run code written for Python 2" not an answer?